# How to implement MultiThreading on PlayFramework?

Tags: multithreading, playframework

I dont know how to implement Multithreading concept on Play framework. Please suggest me how to achieve threading concept on playframework. Thank you

Comment: what do you use - java or scala ?

Comment: and this is a very general question - there is a lot of documentation - try to find it or try to rephrase your question. What exactly do you want ? As for me it very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535826/play-framework-async-processing-and-blocking-i-o-in-java

Comment: @Andriy kuba  yeah.. i need to use scala.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah...so the easiest way to achieve it is to use Akka Actors...
In play you have a built in Akka.system() which allows you to achieve your goal.

For more details see: http://akka.io/